# How to achieve customized polymorphic association in sequelize? Where active sub-classes can switch

Tags: sequelize.js, polymorphic-associations

I am implementing a CRM where we have two stages for a potential customer. First the customer is a lead that gets promoted to a prospect. Similarly a prospect can be demoted to a lead. I have stored the basic information in a super table called customer that has a field named 'Stage' that stores if the customer is a lead or prospect at that time.
I want to be able to perform CRUD operations on both lead and prospect using sequelize. I want to know the standard way of achieving this in sequelize.

I found [association scopes](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/associations.html#scopes) in sequelize closest to what I want to achieve but I don't know if its the right solution. Because I want to query a prospect with its basic information in one go.
Also I am not sure how promotion and demotion would work here. From the example in sequelize doc. Do I need to change commentable value to achieve this?